# Are there any free tools to convert .eot files to .ttf, .otf or any other font formats?

Tags: fonts, software-recommendation, web-fonts

I've been given a .eot font file that needs to be used in a desktop program. So far none of the programs that I use (Gimp, Scribus, Inkscape) can read this font type. Are there any ways to convert it to something else?

Comment: Your question had confused me a bit so I'm doing some research to help you out. My apologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only helpful post I was able to find online is from mid-2008, so it's certainly possible that someone has released a tool since then.

EOT is a Microsoft thing, and it appears to be somewhat proprietary and locked down to discourage reverse-engineering. [From the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.eot):

> Embedded OpenType includes features to discourage copying. Subsetting reduces the value of copying, as subsetted fonts will typically omit more than half of the characters. Other copy protection measures used are encryption and a list of "trusted roots" at the source end, and a proprietary decrypting DLL at the receiving end.

So, even if you can convert, you're probably not supposed to and you're probably not going to get every glyph that was in the original typeface.

[Here's the dated resource that I was able to find](http://securitylabs.websense.com/content/Blogs/3114.aspx) - they point out that they weren't able to find any resources that reverse-engineer EOT files. So, they hunt through DLLs to see how Internet Explorer parses EOT files, and then hook into that method to achieve what they want. A bit over my head, but it might be useful to you.

You're better off talking to the person who provided you the font and explaining that you can't work with EOT. Even if that reverse engineering method works, you're probably not going to get the whole font and you might be violating someone's Terms of Service (the font's or Microsoft's). There are probably very few legit reasons that he or she would only have the font in that format.

Answer (score 1):

EOT is meant for embedding. It by design that it doesn't work in desktop apps.
Either this is a free font, then download the original TTF/OTF.
Or it is a commercial font – then it is simply illegal to convert it to a desktop font and use without a proper license.

Answer (score 0):

Found this website and seems to convert files both ways around! I've tried it with a woff (webfont) and was able to convert and download a ttf desktop font :)

http://onlinefontconverter.com/

Comment: Were you able to convert an EOT file to anything else? I tried and was unable to do so.

Comment: Hi Brenden, I tried and your right unfortunately the EOT file didn't work for me either. Since most of the time more file formats are used for web embedding,I was able to use the WOFF webfont file to convert it in to a ttf desktop font.

Comment: I'm the owner of the website and it previous only worked to convert to EOT format, but today it works both ways

Answer (score -2):

try this: http://www.font2web.com and see if it helps I use it often and so far there are no problems

Comment: OP asked for something that converted EOT to TTF, not the other way around.